# Got error when calculate percent, but code works

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have peace of code to get count of active projects.

```
created() {
        this.loadData();
    },

methods: {
        ...mapActions([
            'fetchProjects'
        ]),

        loadData() {
            if(this.$gate.isAdmin()) {
                this.fetchProjects();
                this.projects = this.$store.state.projects;
            }
        },
    },

computed: {
    filteredProjects() {
            let result = this.projects.projects;

            return result.filter(item => {
                return item.finished === 0
            });
        }

    },
```

My Vuex code for projects:

```
const actions = {
    async fetchProjects ({ commit }) {
        const response = await axios.get('api/project');
        commit('setProjects', response.data)
    },
};

const mutations = {
    setProjects: (state, projects) => (state.projects = projects),
};
```

Then I want to calculate percent of active projects:

```
<div class="inner">
    <h3>{{ projects.projects.length }}</h3>
        <p>Total Projects</p>
    <h3>{{ filteredProjects.length }} - {{ parseInt(filteredProjects.length/projects.projects.length*100) }}
    <sup style="font-size: 20px">%</sup>
    </h3>
    <h5>Active projects</h5>
</div>
```

The result is ok, everything working, but in console window i got:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: result.filter is not a function"
```

Comment: `this.projects.projects` does not seem to be defined yet when the code runs for the first time.

Comment: I define this.projects.projects in created(), what is the solution then pls?

Comment: How do you define it? Please update the question with the corresponding code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to clear error:

in data() added activeProjects: []

then in computed:

```
filteredProjects() {
        let result = this.projects.projects;
        this.activeProject = result.filter(item => {
            return item.finished === 0
        });
    }

},
```

finnaly

```
<h3>{{ this.activeProject.length }} - {{ parseInt(this.activeProject.length/projects.projects.length*100) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `data()` function, add a default value that is an empty array:

```
data() { 
  return {
    this.projects = {};
    this.projects.projects = [];
  }
},
```

This allows for code that executes methods from the `Array.prototype` not to error while your `this.projects.projects` is not yet populated.

Comment: I have this.projects: []; in my data()   :(

Answer (score 0):

This is means that when you use function filteredProjects in result you have not array, maybe undefined, insert console.log(result) before you use result.filter and check what is in the result.

Comment: console.log(result) give me 3 things: object, then mentioned error, then array

Comment: Can you add your vuex code ? When you use fetchProjects,this is a async function, and after execute this function you execute this string this.projects = this.$store.state.projects, in store you don't have a data, because your
the asynchronous call has not yet completed.